# ImageView not showing on emulator

Tags: android, xml, vector

I've some ImageViews in my application. They show up fine on my phone but there's no way to show them on an emulator. I've already tried different version and screen size. In another questions people where able to solve the problem using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` or using src instead of srcCompat, but nothing of this seems to help.

The ConstraintLayout where imageViews are:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title_background_log"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/company_logo"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/zeeromed_text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The complete Activity Layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title_background_log"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/company_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_header">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_editText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_transparent_button_focusable"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondary_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="oppure"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/send_button"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="accedi"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sing_in"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:spinning_bar_color="#FFFFFF"
        app:spinning_bar_width="4dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/security_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon_lock"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_intro_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Ripeti introduzione"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary_text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sing_in"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:text="@string/registration_link"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/security_text"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Sicurezza"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.432"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/innovation_text"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/innovation_text"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Innovazione"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/innovation_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon_cloud"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_editText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="302dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_transparent_button_focusable"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondary_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.414"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't think that my layout structure is the problem, but maybe you could prove me wrong.
Images show on phone with API 24 Nougat 7.0.
I tried emulators from API 21 to 23 because my minimum API is 21.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why scr isn't working but you could try: 
`android:background="@drawable/zeeromed_text"`
instead of : 
`android:src="@drawable/zeeromed_text"` or `scrCompact`
don't do multiple like you did mixing `background` and `src` on the first `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
 android:id="@+id/login_header"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49216128/3974530)

Hope this may help you